# Trying To Make Update Work

Tags: django, post

I want to make the below codes let users update their status in the Django . And their update should display on the same template. But it’s not working.  E.g when a user type in “To be a hacker is not a day’s job” in the status textarea and click on update button below the form. The update should display on the same template for his or her friends to see. Just like how we post status update on fb.

**Model**

```
class mob (models.Model):
    username=models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    state_province=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    body=models.TextField(max_length=10000)
    date=models.DateTimeField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"%s - %s - %s - %s" % (self.username, self.state_province, self.body,   self.date)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return "/post/%s/" % unicode(self.id)
    def get_author_url(self):
        return "/u/%s/p/0" % (self.username)
```

**Form**

```
class mobForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=mob
        fields=('body','username','state_province','date')
        widgets={
            'body':Textarea(attrs={"rows":2, "cols":40}),
            'username': (HiddenInput),
            'state_province': (HiddenInput),
            'date':(HiddenInput),
        }
```

**View**

```
def homey(request):
    #if there’s nothing in the field do nothing.
    if request. method != "":
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/homi/')

    newmob=mob()
    newmob.username=request.user
    newmob.date=datetime.datetime.now()
    newmob.body=request.POST['body']
    if request.POST['body'] <> '':
        newmob.body=body.objects.get(id=request.POST['body'])
        newmob.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/homi/')
    else:
        return render_to_response('meek_home.html', {'mobForm': mobForm },context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

**Template**

```
{% extends "base_meek.html" %}

{% block body %}
<div class="form">
    <form action="."  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <table>
    {{ mobForm }}
    </table>
        <input type="submit" value="Update" />
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Is this example complete? Its not clear to me which template is supposed to be showing the resulting status update. What is `/homi/` vs `meek_home.html` and which one should be showing the status update?

Comment: /homi/ is still the same page with meek_home.html. (r'^homi/$', homey), Just used /homi/ for HttpResponseRedirection. I hope you get my point.

Answer (score 0):

The way you are trying to handle the view is strange. First off Im not sure under what circumstance the request method would be blank. Second, you shouldnt need to redirect the request back onto the same view. And third, when you do the odd way of checking if the POST body is not set with <> you redirect them to the same view without the form data set.

The view logic should be something like this in summary:

1. If request is POST, load the data into the form. Validate the data. If its good then render the template back with the form so its populated with the data on the template. Otherwise render back some kind of error.
2. Otherwise render the template with the default form so its new.

Aside from that whole structural issue with your view, the main adjustment I am suggesting is what to do if the form was set. Remove the redirections. Instead try returning a form set to the model you just saved.

```
if request.POST['body']:
    newmob.body=body.objects.get(id=request.POST['body'])
    newmob.save()
    theForm = mobForm(instance=newmob)
    return render_to_response('meek_home.html', {'mobForm': theForm },context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

I also don't really understand your value for POST['body']. Are you expecting them to pass the actual ID of an object? I thought it would be a message of some type?

**Update per comments**

Your probably getting errors with the code in your comments below becauseyou aren't checking for anything at all before you do it. It might be something like this:

```
def home(request): 

    newmob=mob() 

    if request.method == "POST":
        newmob.username=request.user 
        newmob.date=datetime.datetime.now() 

        body = request.POST.get('body')
        if body: 
            newmob.body=body
            newmob.save() 

    theForm=mobForm(instance=newmob) 
    return render_to_response('home.html', {'mobForm':theForm}, context_instance=RequestConte‌​xt(request))
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What I want is this, when a user update his or her status, it should display the user username, the status update, date and state on the same template. So that his friends or followers will be able to see it and comment or share. Hope you get my point?

Comment: After inputing the below codes, I'm getting: MultiValueDictKeyError at /homi/     "Key 'body' not found in <QueryDict: {}>"

Comment: def home(request):
    newmob=mob()
    newmob.username=request.user
    newmob.date=datetime.datetime.now()
    newmob.body=request.POST['body']
    if request.POST['body']:
        newmob.body=body.objects.get(id=request.POST['body'])
        newmob.save()
        theForm=mobForm(instance=newmob)
        return render_to_response('home.html',{'mobForm':theForm},context_instance=RequestContext(request))

Comment: Just updated a possibly corrected version of that code. Also, I am completely confused as to why you are trying to look up a `body` model object using a string of text as an id? The body field of your mob model is a text field not a foreign key to another model and should simply be text from your form I would think.